# I have a powerscript which works fine with outlook to send out email . How can i change it to send out emails from my gmail account

Tags: powershell, outlook, gmail

```
$x1 = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$FilePath = "C:\Desktop\Review.xlsx"
$UserWorkBook = $x1.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
$UserWorksheet = $UserWorkBook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$UserWorksheet.activate()
$rgeSource=$UserWorksheet.range(“A1”,“D9”)
$rgeSource.Copy() | out-null
$Outlook = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Recipients = 'xyz@Abc.com'|ForEach{$Mail.Recipients.Add($_)}
$Recipients | ForEach{$_.resolve()}

$CC = 'xyz@abc.com'|ForEach{$Mail.Recipients.Add($_)}
$CC | ForEach{$_.resolve()}
$CC | ForEach{$_.Type=2}


$Mail.Subject=“TEST as of  $((Get-Date -Format 'dd/MM/yy '))" 
$oDoc = $Mail.GetInspector.WordEditor
$oRange = $oDoc.Range()
$oRange.InsertBefore("")
$oRange.InsertParagraph
$oRange.Collapse($wdCollapseStart)
$oRange.Paste()
$oRange.Collapse($wdCollapseEnd)
$oRange.InsertAfter(“Thanks”)
$oRange.InsertParagraphAfter()
$Mail.Display()
$Mail.Send()
```

This is the code which works fine with outlook , it open excel file , copy data and paste it in message body and send the email.
Now i want to do same but send emails using Gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using com objects to interact with Outlook (you can also do this using c# or vba), have you checked the sender or senderemailaddress properties ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sender
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.senderemailaddress

Comment: I have this one working for the Outlook, but i want now to send email from Gmail not outlook.

Comment: Just to be sure, you mean Gmail on chrome (for ex) ? Not a gmail account on Outlook desktop

Comment: Yes , gmail on chrome.